# How to setup WebSphere Traditional V9 with colima for development on Apple M1 Silicon machine?

Tags: websphere, apple-m1, colima, websphere-traditional

I was given the chance to try a Macbook Pro for development, and I'm currently trying to run a WebSphere Traditional V9 docker image on it with colima.

I'm running the colima/docker-machine with the following command

```
colima start --cpu 4 --arch x86_64 --vm-type=vz --vz-rosetta
```

and could successfully pull the ibmcom/websphere-traditional image afterwards.

After connecting my IntelliJ Idea to the running colima/docker-daemon, I can create and start containers of type "WebSphere", but the server doesn't seem to start, and I can not reach the admin console under the specified IP for the container, nor does it write a SystemOut.log into the /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ directory.

Only two messages that I can see are

```
Configure Logging mode
WASX7357I: By request, this scripting client is not connected to any server process. Certain configuration and application operations will be available in local mode.
```

and that's about it.

I tried manually starting the server with the /bin/startServer.sh script, but obviously that didn't help either.

I guess there seems to be something I'm missing out on.

Comment: You need to check `SystemOut.log` seems like you are checking wrong log, like wsadmin. And second thing is that WAS is listening on 9060/9043 ports, not plain 80 or 443

Comment: @Gas: Thanks for your input. I was checking all the log-files from the profile itself under /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/.

Comment: Also I tried reaching the WAS Admin console via http://172.17.0.2:9060/ibm/console/login.do and https://172.17.0.2:9043/ibm/console/login.do, but no luck; it doesn't seem to be running. 
Do I have to build my own image with a Dockerfile+Config+EAR to make it run? Thought I should be able to configure it manually for a short performance test.

Comment: If container starts and runs successfully then you can exec into it to check, but I'd assume that websphere process is running. I never used colima so dont have any idea how to use this. Maybe you are incorrectly mapping ports... typically if you use docker you map ports to your localhost, and access via localhost:9043... Here is additional info https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional